# python CGI not working correctly

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, cgi, raspbian

i am new to python , i am trying to write my first python-cgi program

i edited the `default` file inside the `sites-avilabe` directory and here it is:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost

        DocumentRoot /var/www
        <Directory />
                Options FollowSymLinks
                AllowOverride None
        </Directory>
        <Directory /var/www/>
                Options ExecCGI Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
                AllowOverride None
                Order allow,deny
                allow from all
                AddHandler cgi-script .py
        </Directory>

        ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ /usr/lib/cgi-bin/
        <Directory "/usr/lib/cgi-bin">
                AllowOverride None
                Options +ExecCGI -MultiViews +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch
                Order allow,deny
                Allow from all
        </Directory>

        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log

        # Possible values include: debug, info, notice, warn, error, crit,
        # alert, emerg.
        LogLevel warn

        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

i edited this section :

```
    <Directory /var/www/>
            Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
            AllowOverride None
            Order allow,deny
            allow from all
    </Directory>
```

to be as it is now in the file code

and then i created a file called `test.py`  inside `var/www` and here it is content :

```
#!/user/bin/python
import cgi
print "Content-type:text/html\r\n\r\n"
print "<html>"
print "<head><title>MyFirst CGI :) </title></head>"
print "<body>"
print "<p>It works!!!</p>"
for i in range(5):
    print "<h1> hello world"
print "</body>"
print "</html>"
```

of course the apache is running

and this is what i got :

**Internal Server Error
The server encountered an internal error or misconfiguration and was unable to complete your request.
Please contact the server administrator, webmaster@127.0.0.1 and inform them of the time the error occurred, and anything you might have done that may have caused the error.
More information about this error may be available in the server error log.**

i also checked Apache error.log file and there  is nothing related to this script in it

Comment: Check the apache access log also. HTTP 500 error may be log there.

Comment: Did you install the Python modules in mod enabled?